# why display categories on my woocommerce shop page instead of showing products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I don't want to display categories list in shop page. I want to display products in shop page. How can I do? please help. Thanks
Wordpress version: 4.9.5
Woocommerce version: 3.3.5

Comment: please provide us with more details.. we can't help you like this...

Comment: please have a look http://www.myanja.com/shop/. Some products showed in this page before  I updated wordpress core. Now showing product categories

Comment: No shortcode i used in shop page

Comment: Thanks you guys, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the new woocommerce version you find the options for this in the customizer.
you find this under "Appearance -> Customizer -> Woocommerce -> Product Catalog
[image]

You can find more informations under [this link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-customizer/)

Comment: nice ;-) have a nice day